# How to enable virtual memory for bare metal benchmarks on Rocket-chip?

Tags: riscv, rocket-chip

We are testing virtual memory hardware in rocket chip, and want to run test applications bare metal.

In the Rocket Chip test harness, there are a number of toy benchmarks that run bare metal, but they don’t enable virtual memory.  There are a few assembly tests that do test virtual memory.  They use vm.c to enable.

How do we similarly enable virtual memory in the C-code tests (benchmarks)?